# Images don't load erratically

Tags: images

Images load erratically or don't load at all on the pages of https://imsgeneva.ch. For example, https://imsgeneva.ch/the-school/ has an image that is consistently affected by the problem. However, they load when I request them from the server. I am baffled by this problem.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated :D

Comment: Your images URL is `http` and your site is `https`. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple messages about images and some script blocked in Chrome with `(blocked:mixed-content)` reason. Which basically means it doesn't like unsecure `http` resources in secure `https` site.

WordPress doesn't handle this particularly well. It is designed to use absolute URLs and they tend to end up hardcoded in content and such.

You would have to:

- redirect everything to secure version on web server level (unless you need both for some reason);
- update WP data in database for secure links (with suitable search/replace tool);
- update any custom code to use or generate proper versions of links to assets properly.

Comment: Thanks. I feared that it was a mixed content issue. I don't know much about HTTPS and Let's Encrypt. Even if I add the https to hard-coded links the browser still refuses to load images. There's a server config issue. I recommended going to host's support.